# noun clause or adjective clause? There is some ambiguity

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, relative-adverbs

Please consider the following sentence:

> John does not know why Meera left town.

I guess it is a noun clause because the clause `why Meera left town` can act as a noun that is the direct object of the verb `does not know`. and `John` is the subject. what John does not know? the answer is: `why Meera left town`.

But I read somewhere on the internet that said the dependent clause is actually a relative clause and `why` is a relative adverb here.

Which one is correct? If both, then a clause can be a **relative clause** and a **noun clause** at the same time?

Comment: "Why Meera left the town" is a subordinate interrogative clause (i.e. embedded question), not a free relative clause. The sentence is semantically equivalent to "John does not know the answer to the question: 'why did Meera leave the town?'".

Comment: It can be considered a **free relative clause**.  It would be a *bound relative clause* in @"John does not know the reason why Meera left town", but we are prescribed to use 'that' instead of 'why' for the bound clause (where 'reason' implies 'why').